# Add non-friend tester by Facebook ID to Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

I am developing a Facebook app for a client. I want to add the client as a tester to the Facebook app so he can play around with it and give me feedback. The client and I are not friends on Facebook, so I am trying to add him by his Facebook ID, as instructed in the Add Tester modal.

[Add Testers Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ6WC.png)

When I enter his ID, I get a red x with the error message: ***"XXXXXXXXXXXX could not be resolved to a valid user ID or name."*** I have checked that the Facebook ID he gave me is correct via the Facebook Graph API Explorer.

How do I add him using his Facebook ID and get around this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the username instead?

Comment: I had not tried that because I didn't have the username at the time, but that does seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one must use the username of a person who is not their friend to register that person as a tester for your app. (Thanks @CBroe for asking me to try that.)

Unfortunately, the username field is deprecated in the Facebook Graph API for versions 2.0 and higher:

```
{
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) username field is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "GnJd8sMSb7l"
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the best way to get the username from Facebook ID is to browse to https://www.facebook.com/{id} and grab the username from the redirected url, which will be https://www.facebook.com/{username}.